# Incorporating Transition Probabilities in SARSA

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, sarsa

I am implementing a SARSA(lambda) model in C++ to overcome some of the limitations (the sheer amount of time and space DP models require) of DP models, which hopefully will reduce the computation time (takes quite a few hours atm for similar research) and less space will allow adding more complexion to the model.

We do have explicit transition probabilities, and they do make a difference. So how should we incorporate them in a SARSA model?

Simply select the next state according to the probabilities themselves? Apparently SARSA models don't exactly expect you to use probabilities - or perhaps I've been reading the wrong books.

PS- Is there a way of knowing if the algorithm is properly implemented? First time working with SARSA.

Comment: So, the current problem with your approach based on DP is that you have a large number of states, right? In such a case, do you want to use SARSA(lambda) with function approximation?

Comment: Well since SARSA doens't require the Transiction prob. matrix, it just visits each state a random number of times, it serves the purpose. What I am using is the SARSA(lambda) on-policy control method, as defined by Sutton (page 141). Not sure if I answered what you were asking, again, new to the subject :)

Comment: I heard of something called SARSA with potentials, but couldnt find much information about it

Comment: Thing is, SARSA by default "computes" its own probabilities, but I have the exact probabilities (they can be of 4 different values only)

Comment: Ok, yes more or less you have answered my question. I'm wondering if you can achieve an optimal policy faster sampling random states or sampling exactly all the states...

Comment: Well the state-space is 250*8*11, so its quite large... Fact is the DP algo runs, takes some time but it runs, however it takes up so much memory I had to simplify the problem just so I could have the transition prob matrix, even using sparse matrices, hence the idea of using SARSA. Can I incorporate the probabilities when selecting the next state giving an action? E.g. action getNextState(x3), would yield a different result depending on the probabilities. The expectation would automatically be computed through the Q-values on SARSA - its the way it works

Comment: Ok, so, returning to my original comment, if your problem with DP is the large number of states (and therefore memory), which makes totally sense, you want to use some kind of function approximation to store the Q-function on SARSA, otherwise you will have the problem of storing many Q values again, right?

Comment: Actually I'm building upon another person's work, and in his case, he had a (dim1*dim2*dim3)^2 transition matrix (a 6-dimensional matrix). With Q-Values, one only needs a matrix with dim1*dim2*dim3, correct? That alone should be enough to free up a lot of memory...

Comment: As far as I know, the transition matrix is one thing, which defines the Markov Decision Procress (MDP) environment's dynamics, and is independent of the algorithm used to find a solution (i.e., an optimal policy). So, I think I'm missunderstanding something of your last comment...

Comment: Sorry. So basically we need a Q-value for each state-action pair correct? In my case, I would need a actionDim*stateDim1*stateDim2*stateDim3 array, correct?

Comment: Yes if you are using a tabular (i.e., when Q-functions are respresented in tables, with one entry per pair state-action) algorithm, such as tabular Sarsa(lambda). However, you can avoid this limitation using a function approximator to represent the Q-function. In such a case, you obtain two advantages: i) generalization from one state to similar states (which speedup convergence) and ii) remove the requeriment of store very large tables. I will try to elaborate this a little more in an answer in the next hours.

Comment: That is great! Sutton has a chapter for that, starting to read it :)

Comment: However, what should I do with the probabilities case? I know the exact probabilities of transitioning from each state depending on the action chosen. Should I hard-code incorporate it, or should they be ignored? (They follow a simple formula depending on the NormalCDF and the state variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental difference between Dynamic Programming (DP) and Reinforcement Learning (RL) is that the first assumes that environment's dynamics is known (i.e., a model), while the latter can learn directly from data obtained from the process, in the form of a set of samples, a set of process trajectories, or a single trajectory. Because of this feature, RL methods are useful when a model is difficult or costly to construct. However, it should be notice that both approaches share the same working principles (called Generalized Policy Iteration in [Sutton's book](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node46.html)).

Given they are similar, both approaches also share some limitations, namely, the curse of dimensionality. From [Busoniu's book](http://rlbook.busoniu.net/) (chapter 3 is free and probably useful for your purposes):

> A central challenge in the DP and RL fields is that, in their original
>   form (i.e., tabular form), DP and RL algorithms cannot be implemented
>   for general problems. They can only be implemented when the state and
>   action spaces consist of a finite number of discrete elements, because
>   (among other reasons) they require the exact representation of value
>   functions or policies, which is generally impossible for state spaces
>   with an infinite number of elements (or too costly when the number of
>   states is very high).
>
> Even when the states and actions take finitely many values, the cost
>   of representing value functions and policies grows exponentially with
>   the number of state variables (and action variables, for Q-functions).
>   This problem is called the curse of dimensionality, and makes the
>   classical DP and RL algorithms impractical when there are many state
>   and action variables. To cope with these problems, versions of the
>   classical algorithms that approximately represent value functions
>   and/or policies must be used. Since most problems of practical
>   interest have large or continuous state and action spaces,
>   approximation is essential in DP and RL.

In your case, it seems quite clear that you should employ some kind of function approximation. However, given that you know the transition probability matrix, you can choose a method based on DP or RL. In the case of RL, transitions are simply used to compute the next state given an action.

Whether is better to use DP or RL? Actually I don't know the answer, and the optimal method likely depends on your specific problem. Intuitively, sampling a set of states in a planned way (DP) seems more safe, but maybe a big part of your state space is irrelevant to find an optimal pocliy. In such a case, sampling a set of trajectories (RL) maybe is more effective computationally. In any case, if both methods are rightly applied, should achive a similar solution.

NOTE: when employing function approximation, the convergence properties are more fragile and it is not rare to diverge during the iteration process, especially when the approximator is non linear (such as an artificial neural network) combined with RL.

Comment: I apologize for the late reply @Pablo EM, I had seen the comment and replied back, must have had a connection failure or such and the message wasnt sent. Thanks mate, truly!

Comment: No problem! It's a pleasure to be helpful. Simply accept the response if was useful to you.
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work
:)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the transition probabilities, I would suggest not to use methods based on a Q-value. This will require additional sampling in order to extract information that you already have.

It may not always be the case, but without additional information I would  say that `modified policy iteration` is a more appropriate method for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer mtk99, makes sense, though I can't find a lot of literature with strong basis on the subject, and this is part of a thesis hence, the source must be reliable.
Will read about it though, sounds interesting!